# IndexError: list index out of range with Regular expression

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this link 
https://www.seloger.com/
and I get this error, I don't understand what's wrong because I already tried this code before and it worked

```
import re
import requests
import csv
import json


with open("selog.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(["id", "Type", "Prix", "Code_postal", "Ville", "Departement", "Nombre_pieces", "Nbr_chambres", "Type_cuisine", "Surface"]) 


for i in range(1, 500):
   url = str('https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&idtypebien=1,2&pxMax=3000000&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&LISTING-LISTpg=' + str(i))
   r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
   p = re.compile('var ava_data =(.*);\r\n\s+ava_data\.logged = logged;', re.DOTALL)
   x = p.findall(r.text)[0].strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
   x = re.sub(r'\s{2,}|\\r\\n', '', x)
   data = json.loads(x)
   f = csv.writer(open("Seloger.csv", "wb+"))


   for product in data['products']:
      ID = product['idannonce']
      prix = product['prix']
      surface = product['surface']
      code_postal = product['codepostal']
      nombre_pieces = product['nb_pieces']
      nbr_chambres = product['nb_chambres']
      Type = product['typedebien']
      type_cuisine = product['idtypecuisine']
      ville = product['ville']
      departement = product['departement']
      etage = product['etage']
      writer.writerow([ID, Type, prix, code_postal, ville, departement, nombre_pieces, nbr_chambres, type_cuisine, surface])
```

this the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Seloger.py", line 20, in <module>
x = p.findall(r.text)[0].strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `list index out of range` means that something wrong with index `[0]` so check first what you have in `print( p.findall(r.text) )`

Comment: if you get empty list for `p.findall(r.text)` then you could check `r.text` - you can save it in file and open in web browser -  maybe there is some useful information or warning for bots/scripts or captch.

Comment: I run code and sometimes I get page with text `"Oops, une erreur technique est survenue. Merci de ressayer ultérieurement."` which means `"oops, a technical error has occurred. please try again later." and then `findall()` returns empty list - so it has no index `[1]` and code shows error `list index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
x = p.findall(r.text)[0].strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
```

what you need to find in text?

for working scraped on text you need change above line to:

```
x = r.text.strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
```

and then finding something you need

Comment: problem is that sometimes page shows message "Oops, une erreur technique est survenue. Merci de ressayer ultérieurement."which means "Oops, a technical error has occurred. please try again later." and then `findall()` can't find expected text.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because sometimes there is no match, and you are trying to access a non-existing item in an empty list. The same result can be reproduced with `print(re.findall("s", "d")[0])`.

To fix the issue, replace `x = p.findall(r.text)[0].strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')` line with

```
x = ''
xm = p.search(r.text)
if xm:
    x = xm.group(1).strip().replace('\r\n    ','').replace('\xa0',' ').replace('\\','\\\\')
```

**NOTES**

- When you use `p.findall(r.text)[0]`, you want to get the first match in the input, so [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is best here as it only returns the first match
- To obtain the substirng captured in the first capturing group, you need to use `matchObject.grou[p(1)`
- `if xm:` is important: if there is no match, `x` will remain an empty string, else, it will be assigned the modified value in Group 1.